# Does persist and save both call next value of sequence immediately if the Generation Type is sequence?

Tags: hibernate, session, save, persist

When an entity is having an id generated with "strategy=GenerationType.Sequence" and if attach this entity to persistence context using either session.save or session.persist, will the both of these calls invoke the next value of the sequence - "call next value for hibernate_sequence"?

According to JPA, persist call will not need the identifier until the flush happens or commit happens when flushtype is set to AUTO.

And also, when generationType is set to Identity, the session.persist do not make an insert into database but session.save will and that explains why. But in case of GenerationType set to sequence, anything behaves differently?